# SEO friendly URL

Tags: url, seo

Which is more seo friendly URL from below

1. http://www.example.com/products/market-reports
2. http://www.example.com/products/market-reports.aspx

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without the `.aspx`. It doesn't help anyone, except the person interested in how you built your site.

Also, if you change the underlying technology, you can use the same URL without losing the link juice.

Comment: The `.aspx` can also be detrimental to users and indexing agents trying to dig deeper into your site.  It's common that, for the url `http://www.example.com/products/market-reports`, that users can trim off parts of the url at the slashes and still have a usable link: `http://www.example.com/products` and, obviously,  `http://www.example.com` should both work.  With the `.aspx` you lose this conceptual model.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your nice question.

One of the major advantage of having without extension in URL is that they are easier to read for the visitors.

The other advantage of using without extension URL is that you can change the technology they use without having problems migrating URLs (.php to .html or .jsp to .html)

RESOURCE TO MUST READ:>>>http://moz.com/community/q/removing-html-extension-from-url-benefit

Thanks